# Stuck with springcontext.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Can anyone identify what is wrong with the namespace declaration below? I've mentioned all the namespaces and gave references to the schema files. Not sure what else is missing.

Here is my SpringContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
          xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
<annotation-driven />  
<beans:bean id="handlerMapping" class="com.common.spring.RequestMapping">
    <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"/> 
 </beans:bean> 
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />
</beans:beans>
```

It causing the below error.

> The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'property'.
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)

Comment: exception tells it does not expect to see 'property' tag inside bean declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
<property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"/>
```

to

```
<beans:property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"/>
```